# Rock,Paper&Scissors game problem in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

> Whenever I run the code , computer-Point has score 1 before the game
> started . Second issue that I couldn't figure out is that how to set a
> play round for 5 set.  these are the JavaScript code
>
> 1. describe the values
> 2. set computer choices
> 3. set check-winner Function
> 4. set Player choices
> 5. set game function

`````
````
var playerPoint = 0;
var computerPoint = 0;
const userScore_p = document.querySelector(".human > p");
const computerScore_p = document.querySelector(".machine > p");
const result_p = document.querySelector('.result > p');
const rock = document.getElementById('rock')
const paper = document.getElementById('paper');
const scissors = document.getElementById('scissors');
const playerSelection = [rock, paper, scissors]


const weapons = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
// set the computer random choice
function getComputerChoice(){
    const choice = weapons[Math.floor(Math.random() * weapons.length)];
    return choice;
}

function checkWinner(playerSelection) {
       const computerSelection = getComputerChoice(); 
       if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
        result_p.textContent = "Tie";
       
    } 
     else if ((playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors") ||
              (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") ||
              (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock")) {
                 result_p.textContent = "player Winnnn";
                 playerPoint++;
                 userScore_p.innerHTML = playerPoint;
    } else {
                result_p.textContent = "Player lost!!!!";
                computerPoint++;   
                computerScore_p.innerHTML = computerPoint;
    }
    console.log(computerSelection)
    console.log(playerSelection);
}

function getPlayerChoice() {
    rock.addEventListener("click", function () {
     checkWinner("rock");
    });
    paper.addEventListener("click", function() {
         checkWinner("paper");
    });
    scissors.addEventListener("click", function() {
        checkWinner("scissors")
    });
    
}

function game() {
    const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (playerPoint > computerPoint) {
        result_p.innerHTML = "you won the game"
      } else if (playerPoint < computerPoint) {
        result_p.innerHTML = "you lose the game"
      } else {
        result_p.innerHTML = "Drawwww"
      }
   }
}

game()
checkWinner();
getPlayerChoice();
    ````
`````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, player is not going to choose a weapon until they click on 1 of the 3 buttons, so when you call the function `getPlayerChoice()` it actually doesn't mean the player clicked on one of those buttons.

You should process the logics inside the `checkWinner()` function, which is called whenever the user clicks on a button.

```js
let playerPoint = 0;
let computerPoint = 0;

const userScore_p = document.querySelector(".human > p");
const computerScore_p = document.querySelector(".machine > p");
const result_p = document.querySelector('.result > p');
const rock = document.getElementById('rock')
const paper = document.getElementById('paper');
const scissors = document.getElementById('scissors');
const playerSelection = [rock, paper, scissors]

rock.addEventListener("click", function() {
  checkWinner("rock");
});

paper.addEventListener("click", function() {
  checkWinner("paper");
});

scissors.addEventListener("click", function() {
  checkWinner("scissors")
});

const weapons = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

// set the computer random choice
function getComputerChoice() {
  const choice = weapons[Math.floor(Math.random() * weapons.length)];
  return choice;
}

function checkWinner(playerSelection) {

  const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();

  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    result_p.textContent = "Tie";

  } else if ((playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors") ||
    (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") ||
    (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock")) {
    result_p.textContent = "player Winnnn";
    playerPoint++;
    userScore_p.innerHTML = playerPoint;
  } else {
    result_p.textContent = "Player lost!!!!";
    computerPoint++;
    computerScore_p.innerHTML = computerPoint;
  }
  console.log(computerSelection)
  console.log(playerSelection);
}
```

```html
<button id="rock">rock</button>
<button id="paper">paper</button>
<button id="scissors">scissors</button>

<div>
  HUMAN
  <div class="human">
    <p>0</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  MACHINE
  <div class="machine">
    <p>0</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  RESULT
  <div class="result">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I corrected my code but with the your guide and it's work. I still couldn't figure out how to set five round game. I try many ways and I can't find any answer and it's none stop game.